# Find number of unique values in a column

Tags: linux

I would like to know the count of unique values in column using linux commands. The column has values like below (data is edited from previous ones). I need to ignore .M, .Q and .A at the end and just count the unique number of plants

```
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56855-ALL-ALL.M"
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56855-ALL-ALL.Q"
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56855-WND-ALL.A"
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56868-LFG-ALL.Q"
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56868-LFG-ALL.A"
"series_id":"ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56841-WND-WT.Q"
"series_id":"ELEC.CONS_TOT.COW-GA-2.M"
"series_id":"ELEC.CONS_TOT.COW-GA-94.M"
```

I've tried this code but I'm not able to avoid those suffix

```
cat ELEC.txt | grep 'series_id' | cut -d, -f1 | wc -l
```

For above sample, expected count should be 6 but I get 8

Comment: use `uniq` to remove duplicates and use `-f1-4` to remove `.M`, `.Q`, `.A` from each line. see my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

`grep -Po "ELEC.PLANT.*" FILE | cut -d. -f -4 | sort | uniq -c`

1. You first grep for the *"ELEC.PLANT.*" part
2. remove the *.Q,A,M*
3. remove duplicates and count using `sort | uniq -c`

EDIT: 
for the new data it should be only necessary to do the following:
`grep -Po "ELEC.*" FILE | cut -d. -f -4 | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: May I know how to fix for the new data?

Comment: @Prajwal you should modify (or remove) the `grep` part of the command.

Comment: In the edited data the last two lines has only three dots. So '-f-4' don' seem to work entirely

Answer (score 1):

When you have to do some counting, you can easily do it with `awk`. Awk is an extremely versatile tool and I strongly recommend you to have a look at it. Maybe start with [Awk one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/).

Having that said, you can easily do some conditioned counting here:

What you want, is to count all unique lines which have `series_id` in it.

```
awk '/series_id/ && (! $0 in a) { c++; a[$0] } END {print c}'
```

This essentially states: if my line contains "series_id" and I did not store the line in my array `a`, then it means I did not encounter my line yet and increase the counter `c` with 1. At the END of the program, I print the count `c`.

Now you want to clean things up a bit. Your lines of interest essentially look like

```
"something":"something else"
```

So we are interested in `something else` which is in the 4th field if `"` is a field separator, and we are only interested in that if `something` is `series_id` located in field 2.

```
awk -F'"' '($2=="series_id") && (! $4 in a ) { c++; a[$4] } END {print c}'
```

Finally, you don't care about the last letter of the fourth field, so we need to make a small substitution:

```
awk -F'"' '($2=="series_id") { str=$4; gsub(/.$/,"",str); if (! str in a) {c++; a[str] } } END {print c}'
```

You could also rewrite this differently as:

```
awk -F'"' '($2 != "series_id" ) { next }
           { str=$4; gsub(/.$/,"",str) }
           ( str in a ) { next }
           { c++; a[str] }
           END { print c }'
```

Answer (score 0):

My standard way to count unique values is making sure I have the list of values (using `grep` and `cut` in your case), and add the following commands behind a pipe:

```
| sort -n | uniq -c
```

The `sort` does the sorting, based on number sorting, while the `uniq` gets the unique entries (the `-c` stands for "count").

Comment: @Prajwal: how do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do this : `cat ELEC.txt | grep 'series_id' | cut -f1-4 -d. | uniq | wc -l`

`-f1-4` will remove the the fourth `.` from each line

Comment: `cat` not really needed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: question is about getting `uniq` values and not about `cat` or `grep`

Comment: yes but that does not mean using `cat` this way is good practice.

Comment: Can you please suggest fix for the edited data above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[:.\"]+"} /^"series_id":/{print $6}' \
ELEC.txt |sort -n |uniq -c
```

The ouput for the sample you posted will be something like this:

```
  1 56841-WND-WT
  2 56855-ALL-ALL
  1 56855-WND-ALL
  2 56868-LFG-ALL
```

If you need the entire string, you can print the other fields as well:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[:.\"]+"; OFS="."} /^"series_id":/{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' \
ELEC.txt |sort -n | uniq -c
```

And the output will be something like this:

```
  1 ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56841-WND-WT
  2 ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56855-ALL-ALL
  1 ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56855-WND-ALL
  2 ELEC.PLANT.CONS_EG_BTU.56868-LFG-ALL
```